# DATEDIFF returns NULL in BEFORE INSERT Trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have created a *BEFORE INSERT Trigger*. I want to calculate the total days. I have two columns **leave_from** and **leave_to**. Now I want to subtract these two columns to set **total_days**.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `leave_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `leave` FOR EACH ROW
begin
set new.total_days=(select DATEDIFF('new.leave_from','new.leave_to'));
end;;
```

When I am inserting the data into table, the `total_days` are coming `NULL`.
Why is that?

Comment: if any one of leave_from or leave_to is null then output will be null

Comment: Or, alternatively, so store derived data

Answer (score 1):

You are passing strings to `DATEDIFF`. `DATEDIFF` will try to parse the strings `'new.leave_from'` and `'new.leave_to'` as dates, which will fail and thus will return `NULL`.

Get rid of the `'` and it should work: `DATEDIFF(new.leave_from,new.leave_to)`

Comment: @vijayrajsinghsisodiya If this answer helped you, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).